# Elasticsearch Query to Count of Sessions using Historical Data using Serial Date Difference

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Sample Data: https://jsonblob.com/ecc7c22f-eee3-11e6-90ab-abf5eb463423

[image: One User Illustration]

We want to calculate the total number of sessions of our users using hits in ElasticSearch.

Definition of a Session:

- If the time difference between 2 hits of a particular user > 30 minutes, it will be considered as 2 different sessions.
- If the time difference between 2 hits of a particular user < 30 minutes, it will be considered as 1 session.

The attached image will give an illustration of only one user. We want to solve this problem for a collective set of multiple users.

Comment: How do you load your data into ES? Via Logstash?

Comment: Yes using logstash, Data indexed from mysql, felt elasticsearch gives result faster than mysql and elasticsearch helped to find pattern visually

Comment: Also can you share a few sample log files?

Comment: Its from sql simple https://jsonblob.com/ecc7c22f-eee3-11e6-90ab-abf5eb463423 only `user_id` and `updated_on`

Answer (score 1):

Then I suggest leveraging the [`aggregate` logstash filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html), which can be used exactly for this purpose, i.e. [tracking user behavior](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#_example_3_no_end_event).

In your `filter` section you'd need to add the following `aggregate` filter:

```
filter {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{user_id}"
    code => "map['actions'] ||= 0; map['actions'] += 1; map['started'] = event['updated_on'] unless map['started']"
    push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
    timeout_task_id_field => "user_id"
    timeout => 1800 # 30 minutes timeout
    timeout_tags => ['_sessiontimeout']
    timeout_code => "event['session_started'] = map['started']; event['session_ended'] = event['updated_on']; "      }
}
```

After thirty minutes, you'll get an event like the one below and it'll be easy to chart them in Kibana

```
{
  "user_id": "157",
  "actions": 23,
    "tags": [
       "_sessiontimeout"
    ]
}
```

Make sure you run logstash with a single worker thread with the `-w 1` switch

Comment: how to use this aggregate filter with stored data from mysql to es. https://jsonblob.com/ecc7c22f-eee3-11e6-90ab-abf5eb463423

Comment: You use the same logstash config as you now have, but you add the `aggregate` filter in the filter section and re-run logstash .

Comment: But nowhere i can see `updated_on`. Date historgram based on historical `updated_on` not on current timestamp

Comment: You're right, I missed that. But which `updated_on` do you want to use for your session, the first one or the last one? or we can use the first and the last to delimit the session?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include `session_started` and `session_ended` inside the new event.

Comment: have you been able to try this out?

Comment: I tried, but i failed to understand where i'm going wrong. and what will the output of this in elasticsearch. I felt a key value `tags` added to the record. no records having `tags`

Comment: What you'll get in ES is the sample record I showed you above. From that you'll be able to build your session chart in Kibana.